# Continous heat issues with notebooks

Tags: laptop, overheating

My HP ProBook I bought 2 years ago had to be sent in because of heat issues. It worked for a while, now it's getting too hot again. Just shuts itself down. I bought a new Notebook, a much cheaper and less powerful Asus F55A which was said to stay cool in reviews. I already got PSensor measuring 70 degrees celsius during normal use for the CPU which is said to be as much as a CPU can comfortably take. Is there something wrong with Ubuntu on notebooks? I'm on 12.04 64bit btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even I am running ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my Asus notebook and I must say its supercool.

The model number that you have specified does not have a dedicated GPU so maybe you cannot use bumblebee or something.

I also owned a HP before, and I must say it gave me heating problems too.

Do you have any memory-eater heavy-on-gpu package like compiz enabled?

try jupiter, a power management app for linux distros

type these in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Well I didn't enable compiz myself. Is it enabled by default? Will try Jupiter, thanks.

Comment: No its not enabled by default. Since you dont have a dedicated GPU like nvidia or ati, compiz isn't recommended. Compiz makes your desktop looks more beautiful and its more for guys who like eye candy ( like me )

Comment: I have just tried this and after following your code sample, i get the following error: `Unable to locate package jupiter`

Comment: Retired and no longer supported.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/