# My ubuntu macbook pro feels warm, can I solve this?

Tags: 13.04, macbook-pro, temperature

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 in a partition on my [MacBook Pro (MC724LL/A)](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp619), it runs well, I've also installed [Jupiter](http://itsfoss.com/install-jupiter-ubuntu-1304/), [mbpfan](http://task3.cc/projects/mbpfan/), [Intel Linux Graphics Installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2) and updated the drivers. I'm booting with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/), installed in the OS X partition (so to avoid the infamous 30s boot delay).

This is the stabilized OS X temperature report, while just navigating with chrome:

[image: OS X temperature reports]

This is what I get from Ubuntu just upon start:

[image: Ubuntu temperature report upon start]

But this is what I get stabilized after using the system for some time:

[image: Ubuntu temperature report stabilized]

The sad part for me is that, differently from OS X, now I always feel the machine warm, even idle. It's not burning, but I feel my hands siting over something that's aways warm, that's not right (I recall very old notebook models which I used that aways felt warm), on OS X, I would feel such only when doing intensive tasks. By the way, I'm not with fans running loud or something like that, just the temperature that is above, and they run loud as usual, when I start steam to play some game =)

Any tip on how to solve this, if possible? I think I've described all the software I've installed that could help with this, but none helped much...

#### UPDATE 1

Well, my last change was to [enable EFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode). I must do some more tests, I'm running it from battery and I think it got a good enough temperature. When running plugged to the energy source I think temperature elevates.

#### UPDATE 2

I think it's better after enabling EFI mode, maybe I can't get better than this, the only thing left that comes to my mind is undervolting.

#### UPDATE 3

I'm now using ArchLinux with general power management tools like TLP, PowerTop (with services enabled) and macfanctld. It's **much** better than when I used Ubuntu. This is the best upgrade I've done to this machine years back. RECOMMENDED.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continous heat issues with notebooks](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266171/continous-heat-issues-with-notebooks)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu, Solution for that question included usage of Jupiter. I already stated to be using it, and it's not helping.

Comment: I think you should read [this one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85830/41104) for mysterious temperatures problems. Read the question first and be sure that you have checked everything he has done. Also, check the link provided by sml at the near end of his answer for more tips diagnostic of this problems.

Comment: I'd liked all the links you included in this question. Great job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running in a good enough temperature by now. By the way, EFI boot is much faster.

I continue to use mbpfan, and fear a custom compiled update to a very recent kernel.

Comment: As far as I know, mbpfan is working fine on very recent kernels. At least, this is what Archlinux users are reporting to me.

Answer (score 2):

It may be best to uninstall mbpfan and install macfanctld from the mactel repo. 
In General it should use higher speeds and is therefore louder but keeps your MacBook cooler. 
You can configure it to suit your personal taste by editing /etc/macfanctld.conf

Comment: Yes, this is what worked for me.

Comment: macbook with osx 99% of the time runs with 2000 fan rpm. On linux this is the fan speed too and it gets hot without doing anything. So.. it is not a fan control problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most plausible is install a newest kernel. Actually, the IRC series and 3.11.1 looks better for your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I would try resetting your SMC. This can help with system performance, fans (heat), and power issues.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964