# Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac gets too hot

Tags: 14.04, macbook-pro

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro. But whenever I use more than 20 minutes it gets scorching hot. I tried installing laptop mode but apparently it doesn't exist.

I found something about running on efi vs bootcamp. Is that the reason why? If so can anyone explain how to fix it or suggest a link?

Could it be other reasons?

Also I had Yosemite so I used rEFInd

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I get no such file or directory

Comment: There is a typo in command. The correct one is `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

Comment: @Pilot6 hmm do i need to install nvidia driver?

Comment: Is there only Nvidia adapter? There must be Intel too. And you do not need to make pictures. Just copy text from the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install Nvidia driver and also a switch utility.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

Without the driver both Nvidia and Intel adapters consume power and that is why the laptop is heating.

You can check which adapter is working by

```
prime-select query
```

Switch to Nvidia by

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

switch to Intel by

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Or do in in GUI Nvidia-Settings program.

[image]

Comment: I installed and rebooted my computer. How do i switch utility? and how do i verify only one of the adapters is working?

Comment: You can start "Nvidia Settings" program. The switch is there.

Comment: I am at Nvidia settings but do you by any chance know which tab contains the switch?

Comment: Just look around. I do not have this hardware now. And I wrote how to do it in terminal.

Comment: @JayC Added the picture.

Comment: couple more questions:
My nvidia settings doesn't have prime profiles but i was still able to change it to intel on terminal and I get the following message:


update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-331-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-331-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode



When i do query, it tells me it's intel. Is this okay?

Comment: @JayC It is weird, that it does not have the setting. Maybe the driver did not install well. What does same command from my comments show?

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. Device 00fc
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: This solution seemed to solve the fan issue (running full-speed) on my Mac Air as well, running 14.04. Quiet now like a church mouse.

Answer (score 3):

The problem got sorted out for me.
I am running 16.04 on Macbook pro retina 2015

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mactel-support
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macfanctld
```

After installing it, view its manual by running

```
man macfanctld
```

it will show the config file path. Mostly it will be the below path

```
 /etc/macfanctl.conf
```

Open the config file and edit it according to your needs. I will post my config file here which is working perfectly fine for Macbook Pro 13 inch retina.

```
# Config file for macfanctl daemon
#
# Note: 0 < temp_X_floor < temp_X_ceiling
#       0 < fan_min < 6200       

fan_min: 4000

temp_avg_floor: 30
temp_avg_ceiling: 40

temp_TC0P_floor: 30
temp_TC0P_ceiling: 40

temp_TG0P_floor: 30
temp_TG0P_ceiling: 40

# Add sensors to be excluded here, separated by space, i.e.
# exclude: 1 7
# will disable reading of sensors temp1_input and temp7_input.

exclude:

# log_level values:
#   0: Startup / Exit logging only
#   1: Basic temp / fan logging
#   2: Log all sensors  

log_level: 0
```

Save the config file and restart for safety. 
This package seems to run like a daemon on the background and control the fan speed. I can hear fan speeds dynamically changing from the fan noise.

Comment: When you say sorted out, what temperature does your MBPro run at? I've tried every single thing I could find. Including disabling offending interrupts. TLP, Powertop, laptop-tools, fan control daemons, disabling dGPU, etc. I can't get my CPU heat lower than 45-50 degrees during idle. My MB Pro generally runs around 30-40 degrees in macOS, and hardly spikes over 55 degrees. On Ubuntu or Arch it goes up to 80 degrees quite easily.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please refer it now.

Comment: No need for ppa in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Yes, enabling EFI mode has worked for some people: [My ubuntu macbook pro feels warm, can I solve this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345321/my-ubuntu-macbook-pro-feels-warm-can-i-solve-this)

Here is the link to install laptop mode: http://samwel.tk/laptop_mode/packages/tarball

You can disable animations and effects from CompizConfig Settings Manager so that your laptop runs cooler.

http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html gives you a lead how to boot your mac with EFI.

Comment: i just realized that if i'm using rEFInd, i am using EFI instead of bootcamp. But that still makes my laptop burning hot. Also, i tried laptop mode and couldn't find a package.