# How to switch graphics card on macbook pro (mid 2012) with ubuntu in dual boot

Tags: nvidia, graphics, mac, macbook, macosx

Some days ago I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with mac OS and it works very well (although the battery life is very poor).

I saw that the default graphic card is nvidia (NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M).

When I try to switch from nvidia to intel, Ubuntu boots in low-graphics mode.

The current Nvidia driver is `370 open source`, but also it gives me a problem when i try to enter in terminal mode, the screen becomes black.

I have to switch the graphics card because I must work with Linux.

Nvidia:

```
Chipset Model:  NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 1024 MB
  Vendor:   NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID:    0x0fd5
  Revision ID:  0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3682
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 1.9.23
```

Intel:

```
Chipset Model:  Intel HD Graphics 4000
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
  Vendor:   Intel (0x8086)
  Device ID:    0x0166
  Revision ID:  0x0009
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 1.9.23
```

MacBookPro 15" mid 2012

[nvidia-setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdMOQ.png)

Comment: You need to install the Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: already done but not work

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information and the driver version, how did you installed it and what happens when you try to switch in the Nvidia X Server Settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a switch utility associated with nvidia drivers that may be helpful (described on askubuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644907/ubuntu-14-04-on-mac-gets-too-hot)).  The answer in the link suggests installing the **nvidia-prime** package (in addition to the appropriate driver, which can be found using the command `ubuntu-drivers devices`).  After installation, check the adapter with the command

`prime-select query`

and, if needed, switch to Intel with the command

`sudo prime-select intel`

there is also a GUI (described in the link).

Comment: already done but not work.
With driver 375 it boot in low-graphics mode
With driver 378, not work