# Macbook Pro overheating on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, overheating, macbook-pro

I have a 2015 macbook pro dual booted with OS X and UBUNTU. Everything goes fine in OS X but the laptop overheats in ubuntu. I guess the problem has to do sth with the intel driver because the heating occurs even when I'm not doing anything (also checked the `top` command in terminal & cpu usage was ok).

I did the instructions in link ["Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac gets too hot"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/644907/ubuntu-14-04-on-mac-gets-too-hot?noredirect=1&lq=1). terminal output for prime-select intel is:

```
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['mesa', 'nvidia-340-prime']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['mesa-egl', None]
Info: selecting nvidia-340-prime for the intel profile
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
```

After restart output of prime-select query is: 'unknown' again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: 2015 models don't have nvidia gpu, so following that post ("Ubuntu 14.04 on Mac gets too hot") won't help. Use pilot6's command to find what gpu you get. All components of the laptop generates heat, not just the gpu. To find model of your laptop, use `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` Try to google search for macfanctld, lm-sensors,  cpufreq, tlp, and thermald. My answer about these other parts of the laptop and amd gpu is deleted. Also check https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBookPro11,x

Comment: @Pilot6 I have the exact same problem on my retina macbook pro 2014 model.  Running `lspci ...` yields the following:  `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 08)` `Subsystem: Apple Inc. Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller` `Kernel driver in use: i915` `Kernel modules: i915`.  Any suggestions? I'm on `Ubuntu 16.04` Thanks