# Why does my laptop shut down unexpectedly?

Tags: ati, laptop, shutdown

I keep running into the same issue every time I want to run Linux on my laptop. It shuts down all of a sudden in the middle of a session without any warning, and I'm not even able to turn it back on for half a minute or so. I tried different distros like Ubuntu, Mint, eOS, Fedora but it doesn't make any difference. I have no such issues with Windows. Any idea how to resolve it? Or is it possible at all? Thanks a lot.

My specs are:

```
Motherxtremetech.com/board:
CPU Type Mobile AMD V160, 2359 MHz (12 x 197)
Motherboard Name Hewlett-Packard HP 625
Motherboard Chipset AMD M785, AMD K10
System Memory 1785 MB
DIMM2: Ramaxel Tech. RMT3020EF48E8W1333 2 GB DDR3-1333 DDR3 SDRAM (8-8-8-22 @ 609 MHz) (7-7-7-20 @ 533 MHz) (6-6-6-17 @ 457 MHz) (5-5-5-14 @ 380 MHz)
BIOS Type Compaq (03/18/10)
Communication Port Standard Serial over Bluetooth link (COM4)
```

Display:

```
Video Adapter ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series (Microsoft Corporation- WDDM v1.1) (256 MB)
Video Adapter ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series (Microsoft Corporation- WDDM v1.1) (256 MB)
3D Accelerator ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200 (RS880M) Monitor Generic PnP Monitor [NoDB]
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but if it is Ubuntu shutting down, perhaps there will be something in /var/log/kern.log [or kern.log.1].  Look at the time/date to determine which one.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your laptop is shutting down unexpectedly because of heat issues. Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266171/continous-heat-issues-with-notebooks) in this sense or/and you can buy an external cooler fan and put under your laptop.