# Ubuntu 15.04 crashes frequently after some time

Tags: 15.04, google-chrome, crash

my Ubuntu 15.04 crashes frequently after some time. After it crashed it reloads the desktop-manager and shows the login.

I have a Lenove Thinkpad T520 with 8 GB ram, 8 GB swap partition, Core i5 Processor and Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller.

I use Google Chrome with many tabs open very much. I'm not sure if Chrome causes Ubuntu to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your laptop is shutting down unexpectedly because of heat issues. Try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266171/continous-heat-issues-with-notebooks) in this sense or/and you can buy an external cooler fan and put under your laptop.

Comment: could launching google-chrome with --disable-gpu help?

Comment: Have you checked on RAM usage? Heat issues? Install `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` then `sudo sensors-detect ` get the temperature `sensors`

Answer (score 0):

I'm launching google chrome with --disable-gpu option now and it didn't crash any more since then.

However I don't know the reason why this should solve the problem.